# Can I set MySql to ALWAYS remove leading/trailing whitespace?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I know I could write a statement to remove leading and trailing whitespace from a table or column.

And I know I could use a trigger to remove it on an insert or update.

**But is there a way to setup my MySQL DB to just always check and remove leading (and trailing) whitespaces?**

I can't see ever wanting to allow leading spaces, and I have encountered a situation where I have to trim a column. Just thinking it'd be nice to avoid having to worry about it elsewhere.

Comment: what application language are you using to build the database inserts?

Comment: I **was** talking about backend DB management through phpmyadmin. But then realized that the application will be making these changes through the frontend and I should just be trimming the input there (see my _'answer'_ I added below). These pages are primarily php, some js/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

...Embarrassing.

I overlooked the fact that very few people will be doing updates and inserts from the backend.

I obviously should just be trimming user input on the forms/pages where users make changes.

If anyone still has some feedback or suggestions, I'd still interested in reading them.